# How to evaluate comment data through xpath in xslt 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Is it possible to evaluate  comment  data as node through xpath.
The below is the fraction of input I have in my input xml.

```
Input:
    <htmlBody>
    <!-- @charset "utf-8";
    <toc>
        <sections>
            <section id="abc">
               <title> some title </title>
               <pageBreak/>
            </section>
            ...
    </toc>
    -->
    </htmlBody>

The required output should be:
    <htmlBody>
    <toc>
       <sections>
            <section id="ab">
               <title>...</title>
               <pageBreak/>
            </section>
            ...
         </toc>
    </htmlBody>
```

and then I can extract all title  through xpath i.e. htmlBody/toc//title.
I have tried exslt:node-set but not success.

Comment: Have you tried the `comment()` function, e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="htmlBody/comment()"/>`? This will give you the comment as string, though. I don't think it will be directly available as node. In XSLT 2.0, however, you can turn it into a node tree afterwards.

Comment: Yes I have tried this but not able to turn it into a node tree.

Answer (score 0):

If `disable-output-escaping` is supported by your XSLT 2.0 processor you can do e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="htmlBody/comment()">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '@charset &quot;utf-8&quot;;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Or you need to make use of an extension function or XSLT/XPath 3.0 function to parse the comment content into nodes e.g. in the commercial versions of Saxon

```
<xsl:template match="htmlBody/comment()">
  <xsl:copy-of select="saxon:parse(substring-after(., '@charset &quot;utf-8&quot;;'))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

with `xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"` declared..

Using XPath to select nodes is only possible if you use the function to parse the comment into nodes e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="htmlBody/comment()">
  <xsl:copy-of select="saxon:parse(substring-after(., '@charset &quot;utf-8&quot;;'))//title"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion for using extension function saxon:parse. Now it's working fine.

Comment: @ArvindKr, if my answer solves your problem then you should accept it as an answer so that the question is marked as solved on Stack Overflow.